# Decorate methods in derived classes of Flask MethodView

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I thought that I would be able to require login for all derived views by decorating `__enter__` as follows:

```
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.ext.login import login_required
class LoggedInView(MethodView):
    @login_required
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
```

If I add some logging, it turns out `__enter__` is not entered. Similarly, `__exit__` doesn't happen.

What's going on here?

I can modify the style to decorate some other function, but then it's necessary to call `super()` in derived views which defeats the point of doing this to begin with.

How can I enforce this decoration without any work in views beyond inheriting `LoggedInView`?

Comment: How do you expect `__enter__` to be called?

Comment: @KlausD. When any method is invoked, such as a `class Foo(LoggedInView): def get(self): pass`

Comment: No, `__enter__` is called when you use an object in a `with` construct. See PEP 343 for details.

Comment: @KlausD. Whoops. I thought it also worked as I described as a corollary, but I just tested, and you're correct of course. Not sure what I did that it worked in GAE then - is there some other 'pre-method hook' method I could use like this?

Comment: There might be a special wrapper on GAE. I can imaging such a thing is useful in some situations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To decorate the methods of a `MethodView` instance you have to add a `decorators` class variable with the list of decorators to call. See the [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/#decorating-views).

For your example, it would be:

```
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.ext.login import login_required

class LoggedInView(MethodView):
    decorators = [login_required]

    def get(self):
        pass

    def post(self):
        pass

    # ...
```

Note that the decorators are applied to all the methods that are defined.